# Variable defined in server.js, but template gives error "not defined"

Tags: node.js, ejs

What ridiculously simple thing am I missing here? I'm following all the tutorials I can find, and I can't understand what the issue with this is.

I am defining a variable called myVar in my server.js, including it in the res.render() command, but the template can't seem to access it.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const myVar = "foobar";

  res.render('pages/index', {
    myVar: myVar
  });
});


app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
```

index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
  <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Variable</h2>
    <p><%= myVar %></p>

  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <%- include('../partials/footer'); %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The error:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/mysite/views/pages/index.ejs:15
    13|   <div class="jumbotron">
    14|     <h2>Variable</h2>
 >> 15|     <p><%= myVar %></p>
    16| 
    17|   </div>
    18| </main>

myVar is not defined
    at eval ("/Users/mysite/views/pages/index.ejs":18:26)
    at index (/Users/mysite/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/mysite//node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/mysite/ejs-demo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/Users/mysite//node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/mysite//node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/mysite/ejs/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/mysite//node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/mysite/server.js:11:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mysite/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

If I remove the reference to myVar in index.js, it renders as expected. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: I've just [tested](https://imgur.com/a/lIiKVJ0) that without head, header, footer, and got success

Comment: @boolfalse thanks for looking into it. I tried the same thing before posting. No effect. I still get the error.

Comment: Confirming same result as boolfalse.  works when I remove header/footer.

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis Would you mind posting your code? I must be missing something ridiculously obvious.

Comment: @reubengrafy - it was literally your code copied and pasted into my editor.  no changes except to remove the references to the header and footer partials.  I didn't keep a copy, once it was working and I posted the answer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Wow. That suggests to me there must be a config issue.

Comment: Your code is correct it is working without any error, there may be error in configuration.  https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-khorana-hmjde?file=/src/index.js